# Cookies aren't working anymore after deploying MERN app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cookies, deployment, mern

After deploying my MERN app the cookies aren't being set anymore after the user logs in. However, in my local environment everything is working fine. I have deployed both my frontend and backend on Render.

This is the error I am getting on the cookie:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMBqa.png)

This is my frontend

```
  async function handleLogin(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("https://budgetfy.onrender.com/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      response.json().then((userInfo) => {
        setUserInfo(userInfo);
        setRedirect(true);
      });
    } else {
      //alert("Wrong credentials");
      setError(true);
    }
  }
```

This is my backend

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://stevens-budgetfy.onrender.com",
  })
);

//API endpoint for login users
app.post("/login", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({ username });
  const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc?.password);

  if (passOk) {
    jwt.sign(
      { username, id: userDoc?._id },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      {},
      (err: Error, token: Response) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.cookie("token", token).json({
          id: userDoc?._id,
          username,
        });
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.status(400).json("wrong credentials");
  }
});
```

I have tried adding a proxy but this didn't seem to work. Is this the only solution?

I saw that when using vite you add the proxy to the `vite.config.ts` file instead of the `package.json` file (which is maybe why it didn't work the first time I did it).

Comment: This proxy is used only for development, and won't work in production mode. Your code probably worked before because your FE and BE were in the same domain

Comment: @Konrad Ah I see. I saw another solution was to add the build folder from my frontend into my backend and just host the backend on Render to make everything work. Is this a good solution to the problem? I feel like this is a common problem a lot of people run into so I just wanted to see how most people fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `res.cookie` line in your backend to explicitly set the `SameSite` attribute to `None`.

```
        res.cookie("token", token, {
          secure: true, // Set to true if served over HTTPS
          sameSite: 'None',
        }).json({
          id: userDoc._id,
          username,
        });
```